# No battery indications!

Tags: 13.04, battery, toshiba

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on to a Toshiba Satellite. However I have no indications of the battery level in the top menu or anywhere.

I have reinstalled the battery indicator through the software centre but this has not solved the problem.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell the model of your Toshiba laptop? Because there is a bug in Linux by which the battery is not detected in many Toshiba laptops like L640, L650 etc. Please refer to this [link](http://techinterplay.com/fix-toshiba-battery-issue-linux.html) to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! From the comments to the given answers, I think that the complete battery power management isn't working properly on your machine. Could you provide the output of the following command run in a terminal? `upower -d` Also provide the exact model number of your machine. Include this in your question by *editing* it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled "Show battery status in menu bar" under the Power options?

[image]

[image]

---

### EDIT

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `dconf-editor` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In that window, navigate to `com > canonical > indicator > power`, and change `icon-policy` to `present`. Also, try checking or un-checking `show-time`.

[image]

Comment: I have but it made no difference. However my power screen look different to yours. I'm wondering if ubutu cannot detect the battery. However it does work, because if I disconnect from the mains, it will work for a fair few hours.

Comment: Hmm, how does your Power screen look like? Take a screenshot and edit your question to include it. Also, try what I've edited in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Toshiba Satellite Laptop has this issue for years. It's due to their own conflict with the kernel.

How to recompile personal kernel : http://techinterplay.com/fix-toshiba-battery-issue-linux.html

Or just patch the customized DSDT (No need to recompile) , thanks for wissam's advice : http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2011/03/patching-dsdt-in-recent-linux-kernels-without-recompiling/
(**About patching DSDT, from my experience,instead of /etc/grub.d, my machine prefer "/etc/initramfs-tools"**)

Good luck !!

UPDATE  - Ubuntu 13.10, this problem had been solved

Answer (score 0):

you can re-compile the kernel and here's a link explaining how to do that  http://techinterplay.com/fix-toshiba-battery-issue-linux.html

but you can solve this problem without recompiling the kernel 
check this:  http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2011/03/patching-dsdt-in-recent-linux-kernels-without-recompiling/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.